# Getting original text after using stanford NLP parser

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

Hello people of the internet,

We're having the following problem with the Stanford NLP API:
We have a String that we want to transform into a list of sentences. 
First, we used `String sentenceString = Sentence.listToString(sentence);` but `listToString` does not return the original text because of the tokenization. Now we tried to use `listToOriginalTextString` in the following way:

```
private static List<String> getSentences(String text) {
        Reader reader = new StringReader(text);
        DocumentPreprocessor dp = new DocumentPreprocessor(reader);
        List<String> sentenceList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (List<HasWord> sentence : dp) {
            String sentenceString = Sentence.listToOriginalTextString(sentence);
            sentenceList.add(sentenceString.toString());
        }

        return sentenceList;
    }
```

This does not work. Apparently we have to set an attribute " invertible " to true but we don't know how to. How can we do this?

In general, how do you use listToOriginalTextString properly? What preparations do you need?

sincerely,
Khayet

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the mapping of tokens to the original input text after tokenization. You can do it like this;

```
        //split via PTBTokenizer (PTBLexer)
        List<CoreLabel> tokens = PTBTokenizer.coreLabelFactory().getTokenizer(new StringReader(text)).tokenize();

        //do the processing using stanford sentence splitter (WordToSentenceProcessor)
        WordToSentenceProcessor processor = new WordToSentenceProcessor();
        List<List<CoreLabel>> splitSentences = processor.process(tokens);

        //for each sentence
        for (List<CoreLabel> s : splitSentences) {                

            //for each word
            for (CoreLabel token : s) {
                //here you can get the token value and position like;
                //token.value(), token.beginPosition(), token.endPosition()
            }    

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String sentenceStr = sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation.class)
```

It gives you original text. An example for JSONOutputter.java file :

```
l2.set("id", sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.SentenceIDAnnotation.class));
l2.set("index", sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.SentenceIndexAnnotation.class));
l2.set("sentenceOriginal",sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation.class));
l2.set("line", sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.LineNumberAnnotation.class));
```